# Pressing G triggers redraw of windows

Tags: windows-7

Whenever I press [G] some windows flicker for a split-second and render again. This drops FPS in games and creates visual artifacts like empty toolbars in LibreOffice for ~0.1 second. This is especially annoying for me because I use [G] as my push-to-talk-key in Teamspeak 3 (I tried closing it, doesn't influence the redrawing behavior at all).

Windows influenced by pressing [G]:
- LibreOffice (Toolbar flickers, slight input delay)
- 3D Games (Dota 2 FPS drop from ~90 to ~30 for ~1 second)

Windows not influenced:
- Google Chrome
- iTunes
- Skype

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
GPU: GV-N780OC-3GD (Gigabyte Windforce 3x OC / NVidia GTX 780)
CPU: AMD FX-4100
KBD: Razer Blackwidow Ultimate 2013

Notable: System is running with 3x 1080p screens (3x extend desktop).

Edit:
I tried to solve this myself by closing every application that might lead to this behavior (Dexpot, DisplayFusion, Winsplit Revolution, Geforce Experience) and Google-ing for similar problems, but I didn't find any solution nor mention of it.

I first noticed the problem about 2-3 weeks ago, but it might have been there before.

Question: How do I prevent [G] from redrawing/refreshing?

Comment: welcome to Super User. It would be easy to guess what your question is, but we might be wrong. Are we to assume you are asking how to resolve this? Have you done any research? Is this a new problem? If, yes, have you tried System Restore?

Comment: @CharlieRB I edited the question and no, I didn't try system restore because 1) I don't think it will help. 2) I'm afraid it might change other stuff too. 3) My system is quite far configurated for my personal needs and I don't really want to loose any of that. 4) I don't know when the problem started to occur, but it should be at least 2 weeks old.

Comment: I try to troubleshoot starting with the simplest things and work toward the more difficult. If you won't try system restore, then maybe you could run `SFC /scannow`, from an elevated command prompt, to check system files integrity. Or maybe try another keyboard.

Comment: @CharlieRB "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."